# PHP - Create a recursive json array parse in JQuery

Tags: jquery, getjson, recursive-query

not sure if this can actually be done - OK probably can be done but beyond me.  I have a php recursive array function like this:

```
function recursive_array($results) {
global $DBH;
if(count($results)) { 
echo $res->Fname;
foreach($results as $res) {  
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT FID,FParentID,Fname FROM list WHERE FParentID  = " . $res->FID ."" );
$fquerycount = $STH->rowCount();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
 recursive_array($STH); 
}}}
```

which starts on the page like this:

```
$FID = isset($_GET['FID']) ? $_GET[' FID'] : 0;
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT FID,FParentID,Fname FROM list WHERE FParentID ='0' " );
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
recursive_array($STH);
```

This function works well for me. BUT it is "plain" php.  what I would like to do is to create a json array rather than `echo` out the results.  Then to parse the results through JQuery.  My reason is I am using `$.getJSON('etc...')` for cross domain functionality with a "central" DB.  OK I can use Iframes and just create "template" pages at the "central" domain, but I would prefer not to. (I just hate frames/Iframes)

Any suggestions / comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done, actually in javascript:

```
function forall (obj, key, func) {
    if (func) func(obj, key);
    var item = obj[key];
    if (item instanceof Object || item instanceof Array) {
        for (var k in item) {
            forall(item, k, func);
        }
    }
}


forall(obj, key, function(obj, key) {
    console.log('object:'+ obj +'['+key+'] = '+ obj[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<?php 

$json_results = array();
$json_results[] = $res->Fname;

.
.
.

//And after all iterated convert to json.

echo json_encode($json_results);
```

Comment: OK nearly there this would give me something like this ["list 0"]["Sub1"]["Subsub"]["Subsubsub"]["Subsubsubsub"] ["Subsubsubsubsub"]["list 1"]["Subsubsubsubsub1"]["Subsubsubsub1"]["Sub11"]["Subsub1"]["Subsubsub1"] - what I am actually looking for is something a bit more like this {["Forum 0"]["Sub1"]["Subsub"]["Subsubsub"]["Subsubsubsub"]["Subsubsubsubsub"]},{["Forum 1"]["Subsubsubsubsub1"]["Subsubsubsub1"]["Sub11"]["Subsub1"]["Subsubsub1"] } so I can create unordered lists <ul><li>'s for each "parent"